# Selecting a value from select using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have a select input i need populate it from a db and select the value that matches a variable product. I have

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo "<option value='".$row['pname']."'>".$row['pname']."<?php
 if($row['pname']==$product) echo 'selected'</option>";
```

Select Entries are populated from pname and the option with name that equals $product should be selected.
Im getting this error  syntax error,

***unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in***

Comment: Show us the rest of that error message, the part that gives the line number, and indicate that line in the code. Although these errors usually arise because of errors in some line above it, this is the minimum required fro people to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one -

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $selected = '';

    if ($row['pname'] == $product) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $row['pname'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['pname'] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<option value='".$row['pname']."' ";
   if($row['pname']==$product) echo 'selected';
   echo ">".$row['pname']."</option>";
}
```